# Why does shell=True eat up the arguments, and what is the fix?

Tags: python

I am using subprocess.Popen as opposed to os.fork(), and tryin the "shell=True" construct. However, the arguments to be passed to the child process are getting deleted. Any idea why, and what could be the fix?

The files attached are "/tmp/a.py" and "/tmp/a.pl". If I run a.py without any argument, I get the expected results. With an argument, an error message.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python3.6                                                                                                                     

import sys, subprocess

class child_proc:
    def __init__ (self, useShell):
        print ("useShell:", useShell)
        acmd = ["/tmp/a.pl", "Hello", "World"]
        if useShell:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(acmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        else:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(acmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        while True:
            line = proc.stdout.readline()
            if line:
                try:
                    aline = line.decode().rstrip()
                    print (aline)
                except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                    print("Error decoding child output:", line, e)
                    break
            else:
                break

child_proc(len(sys.argv) > 1)
```

The script it is calling -

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl -w                                                                                                                       
die "[a.pl] Missing arguments\n" if $#ARGV < 0;
print "[a.pl] @ARGV\n";
exit 0;
```

This is on MacOS10.13.1. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: from the docs: "If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence." also, you should not use `Popen`, but `run` or `checkoutput`, also you should not use `shell=True`, also you should use `shell=useShell` instead of the `if`/`else`. also why do this in the first place, when you don't actually use `argv`?

Comment: What I got here that if I am using Shell=True, I need to use ' '.join(acmd) instead of acmd - that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. ... If
>   args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

So if `shell=True`, you're supposed to pass a string instead of a list of arguments, which will be interpreted literally by the shell. If you pass a sequence as you're doing now, it treats the first element as the entire command and the rest as arguments *to the shell*. So if you need `shell=True`, pass a string.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("./tmp/a.pl Hello World", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

And be careful not to pass any user input to the shell when you do it this way. As the docs warn, untrusted input to `Popen` with a `shell=True` argument is a *major* security hazard.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `list` as the command container, with `shell=True`, the first element would be treated as the command to run, and then rest would be passed as arguments to the shell itself.

So, if you want to use `shell=True` to run the command is a shell, make it a string:

```
acmd = "/tmp/a.pl Hello World"
```

*Note: Be careful about running something directly in the shell in unescaped form.*

Or, better, you should drop the `shell=True` and make `subprocess` do the `fork()`-`exec()` as there is nothing shell specific in your code.

---

For completeness, if you insist on keeping your current structure, you should do:

```
if useShell:
    proc = subprocess.Popen("/tmp/a.pl Hello World", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
else:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["/tmp/a.pl", "Hello", "World"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

---

Or you can set the `acmd` at the start based on `useShell`'s value, it gets simpler as you can drop the `if...else` construct too by setting `shell` as `useShell` inside `subprocess.Popen`:

```
acmd = "/tmp/a.pl Hello World" if useShell else ["/tmp/a.pl", "Hello", "World"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(acmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=useShell)
```

As a side note, you should use snake_case for variable/function names, and CamelCase for class names.

Comment: why not just `shell=useShell` in the first place?

Comment: @hop: The input command container is different in two cases. I don't see the gain.

Comment: i think the op wants to construct `acmd` beforhand anyway, so there would be the "gain"

Comment: @hop check now.

Comment: My original script didnt have Shell=True part. I was not able to kill the child process (from another thread in the parent), and reading up this site pointed to using Shell=True. So I was trying this, and the child burped. I simplified the code to 30 lines to ask the question here. In my real world, using the Shell construct does not depend on any argument, but acmd is built up as a list using different logic.